# How to provide a mutable struct in Rust to be used by different parts of the program

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm quite new to Rust and faced an architectural problem. Imagine I'm creating a type that provides certain "service", like does something useful:

```
struct MyDatabase {
  state: some_type;
}
impl MyDatabase {
  fn query(&mut self, ...) -> ... { ... }
}
```

I'd like this service to be used in different places, that is, as I concluded from my decades of C++ experience, is best expressed via references to the struct instance from different objects. Because I obviously don't want to create multiple copies of the object, it should exist as a single instance and be used by many consumers.

```
struct DatabaseClient1 {
  db: &mut MyDatabase; // supplied via DatabaseClient1::new()
}
struct DatabaseClient2 {
  db: &mut MyDatabase; // supplied via DatabaseClient2::new()
}
```

With Rust it became impossible because you cannot have more than 1 mutable reference at the same time. And I'm not ok with using immutable references because the `supply` method can change the "state".

The problem starts when I want to create two instances of database clients. The first one is created ok, but the second cannot.

What is the critical Rust thinking am I missing?

Comment: What happens if your two clients issue simultaneous requests to the database? What happens if there is a callback from `MyDatabase` which causes `DatabaseClient1` to call `query()` again, and `query` turns out to be not reentrant?

Comment: Also, take a look at `std::RefCell` if answers are "never happens" and "never happens". Then Rust will check that you don't accidentally get two mutable references in runtime.

Comment: If the database driver allows concurrent access, this should be perfectly fine. I think this type of guarantee should be stated by a person (developer), not enforced by a language. `RefCell` won't help if I understood it correctly, because it will panic if detects concurrent mutable access in runtime.

Comment: "I think this type of guarantee should be stated by a person (developer), not enforced by a language." in that case Rust is the wrong language. It does not trust the developer. If you really want to, there is the `unsafe` escape hatch that allows you do all kinds of crazy things, but having two mutable references in Rust can easily lead to UB in C++ terms. If you're wrapping a database driver from C/C++, you're likely to use `unsafe` anyways. If you're writing your own, you _have to_ handle the concurrency at least somewhere (queue/pool), that's probably the appropriate level to create handle

Comment: @yeputons In fact, the simultaneous existence of two mutable references to the same value is itself undefined behaviour.

Comment: Even if the driver allows concurrent access, _your code does not_. It mutates things and does not (necessarily) does that atomically, so a data race. So Rust is actually protecting you here. If you do mutate them atomically (via atomics or `Mutex`), then `query()` can (and should) take `&self`, and the problem disappears. If concurrency is not required, you can happily use `RefCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** you can mutate stuff behind shared reference if object/lib API provides internal synchronization (synonym to internal mutability).

1. If the database object supports concurrent access (like `std::sync::Mutex` or  `std::sync::atomic::AtomicI64`) than you don't need unique references (&mut _). Shared references (& _) will be sufficient to do everything.
   You type:

```
    struct DatabaseClient1 {
      db: &MyDatabase; // supplied via DatabaseClient1::new()
    }
    struct DatabaseClient2 {
      db: &MyDatabase; // supplied via DatabaseClient2::new()
    }
```

and your code compiles. Then you use shared references to send queries, mutate stuff etc. (their presence in signature of (mutating) method is a sign of internal synchro.)

2. If the database object doesn't support concurrent access (like `String` or `i64`), then wrap it in an adapter that enforces safe access (RefCell, Mutex, RwLock).
   You do something like:

```
    struct DatabaseClient1 {
      db: Arc<RwLock<MyDatabase>>; // supplied via DatabaseClient1::new()
    }
    struct DatabaseClient2 {
      db: Arc<RwLock<MyDatabase>>; // supplied via DatabaseClient2::new()
    }
```

and it's cute. You just get overhead for enforcing borrowing/aliasing rules on runtime.

Comment: `RwLock` doesn't allow concurrent access, which doesn't meet OP requirements (in comments).

Comment: **@ChayimFriedman what do you mean it doesn't?**  
` std::sync::RwLock` is a kind of protection/synchronization.  
Multiple threads can _concurrently_ access the object behind it.  
Either parallelly using shared access or exclusively using unique access.

Comment: Yes, but it does not allow really concurrent access. That is, when one is accessing it the other will be blocked from doing so. OP wants them both to be able to do that in parallel.

Comment: While you can have many shared references at the same time using RwLock and use them in parallel.  
Having ≥2 unique references at the same time is always UB in Rust and highly dangerous in any language.  
If database distributor provides unsafe API with `*mut` pointers then do whatever you want.   
However, it's unlikely that multiple mut refs/pointers is what you (OP) **really** want.

Comment: I didn't say the solution is two have multiple mutable references. This is UB and definitely not allowed. But the solution can't be wrapping the whole thing in `RwLock` either, because it doesn't meet OP's requirements.